# Power on GoPro (5V) with 10-24V using transistor or relay?

Tags: transistors, relay

I have a GoPro 4 and a board for the GoPro Port.
With this board it is possible to power the GoPro externally using 5V and to switch it on.
For power supply I'm using 12V to 24V (from the Car) over a 25m 3 wire cable. At the end of the cable is a Step-Down converter to 5V (Pololu D24V10F5).

Which electronics part (switch in the drawing below) do I have to use so that I can power on the GoPro with the 3rd wire? The Switch has to connect GND with the ON port for about 3 Seconds.

[image: Wiring]

Is there an easy wiring with a Transistor or relay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can just bridge **On** to **Gnd**, then all you need is a basic relay or transistor, in the same manner. A relay is much bigger, but it's mechanical and offers galvanic isolation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCLUBh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, an optocoupler would do the same as the transistor, but still offer isolation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zDAx.png)</sup>

The math for the resistor is the same, the value changes.

> (V - Vf) / If

V is 12 or 24. Vf is the forward voltage of the diode. For the 2n3904, it's 0.7V (Silicon transistor/diode typical Vf). For the 4n35 optocoupler, it's 1.3V. If is current, in amps. It depends on what your target output current is, but since we only need the transistor to be fully on with minimum load, it can be small. For the 2n3904 I chose 2.5mA @ 12V. For the 4n35, I chose 5mA @ 12V. It's typical If is 10mA. The math suggests 4.7kΩ for the 2n3904, 2.4kΩ for the 4n35.

Honestly though, 4.7kΩ would work for both just fine, as a standard resistor value.

Comment: An optocoupler would be the preferred option. Can you recommend any specific type? For that I also need the 4.7k resistor, or a different one?
This also works if I use 24V instead of 12V, with the same resistor?

Comment: Since the transistor is only being used as a switch for what's likely a weak pull-up, yes. 4.7K @ 12V will only allow 2.5mA at the base, and 5mA at 24V. Sized so that the transistor will fully switch on without issue, and small enough that it's not overloaded by the change in voltage. For an optocoupler, the math changes a bit. I'll up date.